# Using Fastlane output variables in shell environment with CLI

Tags: shell, command-line-interface, fastlane

Any chance to grab the `fastlane` output variables or internal environment variables when running one of its commands from a shell via command line interface (CLI)?

The output variables are available when running the corresponding action in a fastfile, but is there also a way to make fastlane write the output variables to the shell environment when its done?